# Bounded variation graphing

Tags: functions, bounded-variation

For function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1, \quad \text{for } 2n \leq x \leq 2n + 1\\[1.5ex] 
0, \quad \text{for } 2n - 1 \leq x \leq 2n\\[1.5ex] 
\end{cases}
$$

on $[-1,5]$, I need to find graph of function $g(x) = V_{-1}^x f(x)$.

Does someone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Have you plotted what $f$ looks like? Have you written down the definition $g(x) = \int_{-1}^x |f(t)| \, dt$?

Comment: Yes I have, but according to the previous tasks we did while calculating variations, I can't calculate $g(x)$, I just don't understand how, because $f(x)$ is constant.